# Any way to use 'defined' operator on object keys?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, conditional-operator

I have a `v-if condition` that fails if a `state` is `undefined`. The state is nested and pretty large (10k+ entries) and might take time to be constructed. A state's `subitem` `[0].expand` of `boolean` type has to be checked in order to pass the v-if condition:

```
v-if="
  // condition required to prevent index [0] from failing
  (state.priceClassData[type]
    ? state.priceClassData[type][0].expand
    : false)
  "
```

I've been trying to refactor this into something more human-readable. In production there are multiple such condition checks in one ternary operator and I am trying to find a way to replace it.

The easiest thing I thought would be to use the `?` `defined` operator on `state.priceClassData.type?` but as you can see, `type` in my case is a `key` and has to be called like so:

```
state.priceClassData[type][0]
```

I've not found a way to apply `?` here. Other attempts include `computed`:

```
const checkCondition = computed(() => {
  if (state.priceClassData[type] && state.priceClassData[type][0]) {
    return state.priceClassData[type][0].expand
  }
  return false
})
```

but I can't find a way to pass the `type` parameter into it, making it always return `true`. I've also tried ordinary functions:

```
function checkCondition(type) {
  return (state.priceClassData[type] && state.priceClassData[type][0])
    ? state.priceClassData[type][0].expand
    : false
}
```

but it only seems to be executed initially, returning `false` and never run again.

I've also tried combining functions and computed:

```
const checkCondition = (type) => computed(() => {
  return (state.priceClassData[type] && state.priceClassData[type][0])
    ? state.priceClassData[type][0].expand
    : false;
}
```

which always returns true or:

```
const checkCondition = computed({
  get() {
    return state.priceClassData
  },
  set() {
    return (state.priceClassData[type] && state.priceClassData[type][0])
    ? state.priceClassData[type][0].expand
    : false;
  }
})
```

which doesn't seem to accept the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use optional chaining and nullish coalescing:

```js
state.priceClassData[type]?.[0].expand ?? false
```

You can easily add more `?` along the chain of property accesses to guard against intermediate values being `null` or `undefined`.

Note however, that you don't actually need to have the whole expression be strictly equal to `false` for `v-if`. `undefined` is also falsy, so `v-if` will not render the element if it's passed an expression evaluating to `undefined`. Thus `v-if="state.priceClassData[type]?.[0].expand"` should suffice.

Comment: I've tried this before but it didn't work. With your help I found the problem though. I'm using objects with string keys, that have only one boolean property. As soon as this property is `false`, the string keys are not being rendered into html by vue. The string keys are then just missing and thus can't be read by any further condition. I've learned 2 things: 1. you indeed CAN use `defined` operator with `object keys` (thanks for that) and 2. don't store information in string keys, if their only property is boolean.